# Change onClick() method of a button via a button

Tags: java, android

I have 2 methods:

```
addCard();

removeCard();
```

and I have **6 buttons** total.

At the beginning all the buttons have as `onClick()` method, the `addCard()` one.
After I click another button (a 7th one) all the other 6 should change their `onClick()` method from `addCard()` to `removeCard()`.

**How do I** do that?
Just to let you know what I thought, I started making these 2 methods as normal ones for buttons, so they take a View v as parameter, any way to really "**swap" the methods**?

addCard():

```
public void addCard(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.first :
            demoniacList.add(new Demoniac());
            first.setEnabled(false);
        case R.id.second :
            guardList.add(new Guard());
            second.setEnabled(false);
        case R.id.third :
            masonsList.add(new Masons());
            masonsList.add(new Masons());
            third.setEnabled(false);
        case R.id.fourth :
            mediumList.add(new Medium());
            fourth.setEnabled(false);
        case R.id.fifth :
            if (demoniacList.size() + guardList.size() + masonsList.size() +
                    mediumList.size() + villagerList.size() + werehamsterList.size() < players.size()-1) {
                villagerList.add(new Villager());
            } else {
                villagerList.add(new Villager());
                fifth.setEnabled(false);
            }
        case R.id.sixth :
            werehamsterList.add(new Werehamster());
            sixth.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: have a master `onClick()` method with logic inside that determines which method to call.  All buttons reference the master onClick().

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it this way -

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        ...
        mButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        ...
        mButton6.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            ...
            case 6:
                if(/* Button 7 is present / clicked */) {
                    removeCard();
                } else {
                    addCard();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact is, when the 7th button is clicked, each button should have as onClick method the remove one instead of the add one

Comment: Something like a ( to be clear, or trying to be) setOnClickMethod(removeCard());

Comment: Set a flag when 7th button is clicked. Then based on the flag, call addCard or removeCard.

Comment: A flag is a boolean that you set when the button is clicked.

Comment: Right! Will try and let you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable as given in the below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private boolean isAdd=true;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
    mButton0.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
    mButton6.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case 0:
            if(isAdd) {
                addCard();
            } else {
                removeCard();
            }
        case 1:
            if(isAdd) {
                addCard();
            } else {
                removeCard();
            }
        ...
        case 6:
            if(isAdd) {
                addCard();
                isCard=false;
            } else {
                removeCard();
                isCard=true; 
            }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use some kind of state representation to do this... Maybe in the view? Perhaps a boolean showRemoveNotAddButton var?

Then just switch on that var in whatever handling method is appropriate.

Your toggle button click handler should change that boolean and then re-render.

Render should have access to that boolean, and be able to know what kind of button to render.